# Gremlin: recursive summation

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases

Given a simple MLM set of data:

```
g.addV('user').property('id', 1).as('1')
  addV('user').property('id', 2).as('2').
  addV('user').property('id', 3).as('3').
  addV('user').property('id', 4).as('4').
  addV('user').property('id', 5).as('5').
  addV('user').property('id', 6).as('6').
  addV('user').property('id', 7).as('7').
  addV('point').property('value', 5).as('p1')
  addV('point').property('value', 5).as('p2').
  addV('point').property('value', 5).as('p3').
  addV('point').property('value', 5).as('p4').
  addV('point').property('value', 5).as('p5').
  addV('point').property('value', 5).as('p6').
  addV('point').property('value', 5).as('p7').
  addE('sponsors').from('1').to('2').
  addE('sponsors').from('1').to('3').
  addE('sponsors').from('1').to('4').
  addE('sponsors').from('2').to('5').
  addE('sponsors').from('3').to('6').
  addE('sponsors').from('4').to('7').
  addE('hasPoints').from('1').to('p1').
  addE('hasPoints').from('2').to('p2').
  addE('hasPoints').from('3').to('p3').
  addE('hasPoints').from('4').to('p4').
  addE('hasPoints').from('5').to('p5').
  addE('hasPoints').from('6').to('p6').
  addE('hasPoints').from('7').to('p7').
  iterate()
```

How can I produce the following JSON:

```
{
  "1": x,
  "2": y,
  "3": z,
  ...
}
```

Where 1/2/3 are the user IDs, and x/y/z are the summation of the user's points and all his sponsored users' points (i.e. user1's points would be the sum of all users recursively under him - u2 + u3 + u4 + u5 + u6 + u7, and same of user2/3/4 etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by grouping the users by `id` and the sum of the points values

```
g.V().hasLabel('user')
  group().by(id).
    by(repeat(out()).
      emit(hasLabel('point')).values('value').sum())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/6j

Comment: The query works great :) Do you know how to get the total summation for each user, but based on some predicate, exclude a sum from the total for a user? For e.g.:
- user1 has children 2, 3, 4. The total sum of user1 is u2 + u3 + u4.
- Based on a predicate (e.g. if u2's total sum is more than 5 points), exclude it from the calculation for u1, so now it's only u3 + u4.
- The ultimate goal is to get the total points for u1 (excl. the total points for u2). The difficulty I'm facing is with the recursive calculation (i.e. get u2's totals first, check it against a predicate and exclude from u1).

Comment: That's not a simple question. I think you should open another question with a more complex example and what you would like to accomplish

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.